# What is the function of the /gps page?

Tags: discussion, support

While visiting Super User, I get this error in the error console on Firefox:

> Timestamp: 5/15/2013 10:10:28 AM 
>   Error: no element found 
>   Source File: https://superuser.com/gps/event 
>   Line: 1

Attempting to visit `/gps` or `/gps/event` directly results in a 404 ("page not found").
What is the function of the `/gps` page, and are there any other "hidden" subpages of this kind?

Comment: It helps in establishing whether or not your questions are "too localized"....

Comment: We're always watching you

Comment: Seriously, I suspect this is for geolocation purposes and is used to determine the correct [CDN](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cdn) to use.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is not a page you can visit but an ajax end-point that gets posted to:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/gps/event',
```

This code in method `send`(duh) is found in the [full.js](http://dev.sstatic.net/Js/full-anon.en.js?v=4ca89b90e888) in the namespace `gps`:

```
// Begin 20_Analytics.js
StackExchange.gps = (function () {
```

Based on the comments and a little bit forensics we find that it has functions to bind click events to items in the DOM, as explained in this comment:

> Binds ONE INVOCATION of gps.track per anchor (or any clickable element) having class "js-gps-track"  and a data attribute with one or move events to be tracked.

In the site-switcher I see this html:

```
<a href="//meta.stackexchange.com" 
   class="site-link js-gps-track" 
   data-id="4" 
   data-gps-track="site.switch({ target_site:4, item_type:3 }),
     site_switcher.click({ item_type:1 })">
```

When you click in the site-switcher you'll see event being posted to `gps/event` if you open the network panel of the Developer Console of your browser:

```
[{"evt":"site.switch",
  "properties":{
      "target_site":1,
      "item_type":3},
  "now":1438454191590}]
```

Now we know what happens on that end-point, that it gets data from our clicks and that those events are sent to the server.

I speculate on its use: to improve navigation, to measure which features are used and which aren't, to verify the effectiveness of ads and maybe more. Some of this data gets revealed when presenting new features but most of the collected data is a valuable asset that is kept secret.

Comment: I don't know Ajax (I've only started to learn web development) but this answer makes a lot of sense. Thanks. :)

Comment: For uBlock users (or generally people who really don't want this type of tracking): both the Easy Privacy list and one of the AdGuard lists contains rules to block `/gps` around the SE network. There might be more lists blocking /gps, but these are the ones I found while looking into it